# Examples of order-preserving, metric-preserving and addition-preserving functions on $\Bbb R$

Tags: category-theory

I just started reading [Seven Sketches in Compositionality: An Invitation to Applied Category Theory](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-s097-applied-category-theory-january-iap-2019/lecture-videos-and-readings/18-s097iap19textbook.pdf), just for the fun of it. On p.2 I stumbled upon this basic exercise:

> *Exercise 1.1.* Some terminology: a function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is said to be
>
> a)*order-preserving* if $x\le y$ implies $f(x)\le f(y)$ $\forall x,y\in\Bbb R$
>
> b)*metric preserving* if $\left\lvert x-y\right\rvert = \left\lvert f(x)-f(y)\right\rvert$
>
> c)*addition-preserving* if $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$
>
> For each of these three properties defined above-call it $foo$-find an $f$ that is $foo$-preserving and example for an $f$ that is not $foo$-preserving.

I started with $f(x)=e^x$ and quickly realised that it is neither metric-preserving nor addition-preserving. Next, the most obvious example: $f(x)=x$, the identity function hit my mind. The function is clearly $foo$-preserving. However, I could not think of any more functions. I rearranged the terms for metric-preservation conditions and found that: $$\left\lvert \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\right\rvert = 1$$From this, I deduced absolute value function over restricted domains might work, but $f$ is mapped on $\Bbb R$. Hence, I have loads of examples for functions which are not $foo$-preserving, but only one for $foo$-preserving. Here's my question:

> **Is the identity function the only $foo$-preserving function?**

Just to clarify, I don't have a rigorous mathematical background. As such, if the answer requires some pre-requisite knowledge of other advanced math topics(analysis, topology and the likes), I'd appreciate references for the terminology and notions involved.

**Edit**: As brought to my attention by @Joe, $foo$-preserving refers to satisfying at least one of the three properties, and not necessarily simultaneously satisfying all. This, however, does not make a substantial difference to the solution being sought.

Comment: The only function satisfying all three properties is the identity function.

Comment: “foo-preserving” doesn’t mean satisfying all three simultaneously, does it? As written above, it’s asking for functions that preserve/ don’t preserve each property one at a time. You’ve found a function that is order preserving.

Comment: @Joe I interpreted $foo$-preserving as satisfying all three properties simultaneously. As highlighted in the answer below, the identity function is the only such $foo$-preserving function.

Comment: It says, “For each of these three properties“, so it’s asking you to find functions that preserve/don’t preserve each property considered independently.

Comment: @Joe Perhaps you are right. I overlooked the word 'each'. Either way, I now know of a function which satisfies all the three properties, and those which don't.

Comment: @Joe the identity function :p none besides that.

Comment: @Joe Didn't realise that. Although an internet search didn't yield anything, and this question is the top result when searching for "addition preserving functions on R". Should I expand the scope of this question?

Comment: @Joe I'll post a separate question about examples of addition-preserving and/or metric preserving-functions on $\Bbb R$. I certainly want to learn more about them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f$ be addition-preserving, then we have
$$ f(0)=f(0+0)=f(0)+f(0) $$
and hence $f(0)=0$. If $f$ is also metric-preserving, then we have
$$ \vert f(x)\vert = \vert f(x) - 0 \vert = \vert f(x) - f(0) \vert = \vert x-0 \vert = \vert x \vert. $$
This means that $f(x) \in \{\pm x\}$. So if $f$ is order-preserving, then $f(x)=x$.

**Added:** In fact one can show that addition-preserving implies that for all $q\in\mathbb{Q}, x\in \mathbb{R}$ holds $f(qx)=q f(x)$ and so we will get for all $q\in \mathbb{Q}$
$$ f(q)= q \cdot f(1). $$
Instead of metric-preserving, we could also make the weaker assumption that our map is continous and we would get for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$
$$ f(x) = f(1) \cdot x. $$ 
So, these are still reasonable maps. However, be aware that if we only assume addition-preserving, then hell might break loose and you get a zoo of nasty functions.

Comment: I can't think of any elementary addition-preserving function besides the identity function. Maybe I'll look up for more of them.

Comment: The function $f(x)=2x$ is addition-preserving. As $$ f(x+y)=2(x+y)=2x+2y = f(x)+f(y). $$ In general $f(x)=cx$ is addition-preserving. However, as mentioned in my answer, those are "the nice guys".

Comment: In response to a separate question I've been told about the 'nice guys', and warned that the 'bad guys' appear if the Axiom of Choice is invoked.

Comment: Indeed, I did not want to get too much into details. The point is that you want to pick a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis of $\mathbb{R}$ (that is very you use the axiom of choice). I did not write about this to avoid potential confusion (as you wrote that you don't have a "rigorous mathematical background").