# Examples of addition-preserving and/or metric-preserving functions on $\Bbb R$

Tags: category-theory

My [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3684896/examples-of-order-preserving-metric-preserving-and-addition-preserving-function) was specifically concerned with the identity function being the only order-, metric- and addition-preserving function on $\Bbb R$. With this question, I seek answers to the following:

> 1.Examples of addition-preserving functions on $\Bbb R$
>
> 2.Examples of metric-preserving functions on $\Bbb R$
>
> 3.Examples of functions on $\Bbb R$ which are both metric- and addition-preserving.

I failed to find useful references/examples on the internet, so I would appreciate references/further readings to be included within the answer(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Addition-preserving: $f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y)$.  If $f$ is continuous (or measurable, or locally bounded), then such $f$ must be of the form $f(x) = ax$.  But there are other solutions, extremely badly behaved, if you believe the Axiom of Choice.

Metric-preserving: $|f(x) - f(y)| = |x-y|$.  Such a map must be of the form $f(x) = ax+b$ where either $a=1$ or $a=-1$.  This generalizes to Euclidean geometry.  A metric-preserving map $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is of the form $f(x) = Ax+b$ where $A$ is an $n \times n$ orthonormal matrix, and $b \in \mathbb R^n$.

Both metric and addition preserving: $f(x) = ax$ where either $a=1$ or $a=-1$.

Comment: I've been told about these 'badly behaved functions' in my previous question too. I have no idea why mathematicians hate the Axiom of Choice, though.

Comment: Well, most of us don't :) I like being able to pick a basis and also to have Zorn's lemma

Comment: The "badly behaved" is not for the axiom of choice, but for the functions. Those guys do not match the mental image we have of linear functions.